# Get data from stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I made a stored procedure to get data like: `select * from customer` and then I made a model in Entity Framework through 1 function `getcustomer`. What code should I write to get the list from the stored procedure?

```
public List<Customer> getCustomerWithsp()
    {
        Database1Entities1 context = new Database1Entities1();
        List<Customer> cust = new List<Customer>();
        cust = context.getcustomer().tolist(); //What should I write here?
        return cust;
    }
```

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2011/03/01/using-stored-procedures-with-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-application.aspx

Comment: Insert update delete process are working properly but problem regarding select case is it compulsory write to query its dont call directly Store procedure.          like  cust = context.getcustomer();

Comment: hello Tariqulazam ,                                               Insert update delete process are working properly but problem regarding select case is it compulsory write to query its dont call directly Store procedure.          like  cust = context.getcustomer();

Comment: You have to create function import. Try to follow the article at http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/12/17/ado-net-entity-framework-tools-stored-procedures.aspx